# Tish'a Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

142-129 BCE - Jewish autonomy under Hasmoneans.

129-63 BCE - Jewish independence under Hasmonean monarchy.

(In [129 BCE](http://cojs.org/cojswiki/The_Hasmonean_Dynasty), [Antiochus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_VII_Sidetes) died and the [Selucid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_Empire) empire collapsed, so the Jews were able to regain independence in the Land of Israel.)